# Pm hide adb command

Tags: android, adb

I'm trying to hide/disable an app using `pm hide com.myapp` but I'm getting an error `Error: java.lang.SecurityException: Neither user 10225 nor current process has android.permission.MANAGE_USERS.`
I'm using an unrooted phone could anyone tell me why I can't use pm hide or if there's another command I can use

Answer (score 3):

In case anyone is still looking for an answer to this, disabling OEM bloatware through `adb` is still possible on Android M+ using `pm uninstall`. While its true that uninstalling a system app requires root access, you can however uninstall the app for a particular user (yourself or `user 0`) without any root like this:

```
pm uninstall --user 0 com.micromax.trendingapps
```

But be careful and make absolutely sure that its a bloatware you are uninstalling because the above changes are permanent! You may not undo the damage done to a system app without factory resetting your device again.

Answer (score 1):

Android disabled this feature in some security update in android 6

Comment: It's available in Android 10: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/android-10.0.0_r1/core/java/android/content/pm/PackageManager.java#6384